# Stringstream Line Processing

Tags: c++, arrays, string

the code below copies a text file into a vector and then streams all the lines in the text file to the clipboard.

I want to copy the text file into a vector and stream all the lines BUT I want to process each line with `////code..` before the next I am struggling with the loop logic.

**E.G**

line 1 is loaded into stream and copied to clipboard, now do something to line 1

next>

line 2 is loaded into stream and copied to clipboard, now do something to line 2
and so on..

---

`input.txt` looks like this **:**

```
000000
000001
000002
000003
000004
000005
000006
000007
000008
```

So take `000000` copy it to clipboard run `////code..` on `000000` and then do the same to `000001`, `000002`, `000003`, `000004`.....and so on.

Any advice will be appreciated thanks.

**CODE BELOW:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <direct.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

void toClipboard(HWND hwnd, const std::string &s);

/*
* It will iterate through all the lines in file and
* put them in given vector then copy vector to clipboard.
*/

//1. Open file and put each line into a vector.
bool getFileContent(std::string fileName, std::vector<std::string> & vecOfStrs)
{

    // Open the File
    std::ifstream in(fileName.c_str());

    // Check if object is valid.
    if (!in)
    {
        std::cerr << "Cannot open the File : " << fileName << std::endl;
        return false;

    }

    std::string str;
    // Read the next line from File untill it reaches the end.
    while (std::getline(in, str))
    {
        // Line contains string of length > 0 then save it in vector.
        if (str.size() > 0)
            vecOfStrs.push_back(str);
    }
    // Close The File.
    in.close();

    return true;

}


//2. Declare clipboard functions at file scope.
void toClipboard(HWND hwnd, const std::string &s) {
    OpenClipboard(hwnd);
    EmptyClipboard();
    HGLOBAL hg = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, s.size() + 1);
    if (!hg) {
        CloseClipboard();
        return;
    }
    memcpy(GlobalLock(hg), s.c_str(), s.size() + 1);
    GlobalUnlock(hg);
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hg);
    CloseClipboard();
    GlobalFree(hg);
}



int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vecOfStr;
    // Get the contents of file in a vector.
    bool result = getFileContent("input.txt", vecOfStr);
    if (result)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        // Populate
        std::copy(vecOfStr.begin(), vecOfStr.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ss, "\n"));

        ////code..
        //Do something to line 1 of stream
        //Do something to line 2 of stream
        //Do something to line 3 of stream
        //.....
        //

        // Display
        std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;

        // Copy vector to clipboard.
        size_t len = strlen(ss.str().c_str());
        // Get desktop windows and the call toClipboard.
        HWND hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
        toClipboard(hwnd, ss.str());
        std::getchar();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to do some processing on the input -read from text file- and then send the processed data to the clipboard? Right?
You have all the data in your vector of strings. Each element in the vector is a line in the file, why don't you just loop your vector -before copying to the stream- do processing then copy it?

Comment: What does *run `////code..` on `000000`* mean?

Comment: @super `////code..` means string processing like add `_1` or `,` or copy only the line `000000` or copy only the line `000003`

Comment: @MALKAVIAN Ok, and how would you know what to do with a certain line? I'm guessing you do different things to different lines.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define what "Do Something" is, and use it to transform each element.

```
std::string DoSomething(std::string line)
{
    return "Some " + line + " Change";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vecOfStr;
    // Get the contents of file in a vector.
    bool result = getFileContent("input.txt", vecOfStr);
    if (result)
    {
        // Transform
        std::transform(vecOfStr.begin(), vecOfStr.end(), vecOfStr.begin(), DoSomething);

        // Populate & Display
        std::stringstream ss;
        std::copy(vecOfStr.begin(), vecOfStr.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ss, "\n"));
        std::copy(vecOfStr.begin(), vecOfStr.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

        // Copy vector to clipboard.
        size_t len = strlen(ss.str().c_str());
        // Get desktop windows and the call toClipboard.
        HWND hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
        toClipboard(hwnd, ss.str());
        std::getchar();
    }

    return 0;
}
```